# Flutter : Exception then the page Builds Correctly

Tags: api, flutter, asynchronous

Hello everyone i have a simple class that will check if the user have access token from Shared Preferences then it will check if the user is admin or not and if it doesn't have access token it will redirect him to login page

the thing is when i open the app there is this flashing error appears on the screen for 1 second then it disappears

the reason behind that is that i am sending async request but the build method isn't async so the build method builds and of course due to missing data it will through an exception and when the data is available i call setState then it rebuilds correctly

what i want to do is refactor this code so that this flashing message will not appear again for the user my code is simple please share any tip you have

code

```
class _AuthenticationPageState extends State<AuthenticationPage>{
  String _accessToken;
  var _userData;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchAccessToken();
    fetchUser();
  }

  fetchAccessToken() async{
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String accessToken = prefs.getString('accessToken');
    setState(() {
      _accessToken = accessToken;
    });
  }

 fetchUser() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String accessToken = prefs.getString('accessToken');
    http.Response response = await http.get(
      '$webSiteUrl/api/user',
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer $accessToken'
      },
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var userData = json.decode(response.body);
      setState(() {
        _userData = userData;
      });
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load User Data');
    }
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      if (_accessToken == null){
        return LoginPage();
      }else
      if(_userData['is_admin'] == 1){
        return Text('you are admin');
        }
        return Text('you are user');
      }
  }
```

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: There is no loading time widget setup in your code. Consider `ConnectionState.waiting` and return any ProgressIndicator widget before displaying data on screen.

Comment: great this is exactly what i want but to use `ConnectionState.waiting` do i need to use StreamBuilder or FutureBuilder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `bool` `isLoading` to control when `isLoading` is `true` display `CircularProgressIndicator()`
In demo code, I use 2 seconds delay to simulate network delay
You can test with `_accessToken = null;` and `_accessToken = "test";` to see effect in working demo

code snippet

```
fetchUser() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String accessToken = prefs.getString('accessToken');
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {});
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
      //_accessToken = null;
      _accessToken = "test";
      _userData = {"is_admin": 1};
    });

... 
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isLoading) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    } else {
      if (_accessToken == null) {
        return LoginPage();
      } else if (_userData['is_admin'] == 1) {
        return Text('you are admin');
      }
      return Text('you are user');
    }
  }
```

working demo

[image]

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class AuthenticationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AuthenticationPageState createState() => _AuthenticationPageState();
}

class _AuthenticationPageState extends State<AuthenticationPage> {
  String _accessToken;
  var _userData;
  bool isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
      fetchUser();
    });

  }

  fetchAccessToken() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String accessToken = prefs.getString('accessToken');
    setState(() {
      _accessToken = accessToken;
    });
  }

  fetchUser() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String accessToken = prefs.getString('accessToken');
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {});
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
      //_accessToken = null;
      _accessToken = "test";
      _userData = {"is_admin": 1};
    });

    /*http.Response response = await http.get(
      '$webSiteUrl/api/user',
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken'
      },
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var userData = json.decode(response.body);
      setState(() {
        _userData = userData;
      });
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load User Data');
    }*/
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isLoading) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    } else {
      if (_accessToken == null) {
        return LoginPage();
      } else if (_userData['is_admin'] == 1) {
        return Text('you are admin');
      }
      return Text('you are user');
    }
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Login"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Login Page:',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: AuthenticationPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much the is loading solution is a simple and a great solution

Answer (score 0):

Since the _userData is also set by a future it might be null as well.

So add this condition

```
if (_accessToken == null) {
  return LoginPage();
} else if (_userData == null) {
  return // some waiting widget
} else if (...) {
  ...
}
```